# Rails routes for paths with characters outside of US-ASCII have stop working in Rails 4.1.2 with Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a route:

```
get "people/*name" => 'tools#biography', :as => 'person', :format => false
```

Which allows people to be looked up by name - for example myyapp.com/people/Andrea Šašinková - previously that url correctly loaded the biography. That now fails with an ActionController::BadRequest error.

This stopped working between Rails 4.1.1 and 4.1.2

To simply reproduce this create a new rails app with a controller called other and an action called index and add this route:

```
get 'other/*id' => 'other#index', :format => false
```

Now calling localhost:3000/other/ková

Will cause the BadRequest error, roll rails back to 4.1.1 and it works again.

The url is obviously % encoded but by the time it gets into action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb it's failing because of the value is encoded as US-ASCII so valid_encoding? returns false. I can't figure out where in the rails code the parameters are set and their encoding is determined. If I patch the rails code to force encoding to utf-8 then everything works again.

Comment: Rails 4.1.3 is out. Have you tried in it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on 4.1.3 or 4.1.4 either. I've raised a bug on rails, written a patch and it's in the process of being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I've raised a bug on rails, the owner has figured it out and is in the process of fixing it. Here's the bug which I've included a patch with:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16104

Note that it doesn't happen if you are using ruby >= 2 as the default encoding there has changed to utf-8